# Refresh Razor Page ViewComponent from Control class OnPost method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to refresh the ViewComponent from OnPost() method of the razor page. The ViewComponent is loading properly while it is invoked from the razor page using the following code:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Menu", new { parameters... })
```

But when called from the Razor page code from OnPost() method, it is not working. I have tried to follow the DontNet tutorials but could not reload the ViewComponent. I tried debugging the code to see whether the method is calling InvokeAysnc() method, but it is not calling.

Here is the code I am trying:

*MenuViewComponent*

```
public class MenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(param1, param2, param3)
    {
        return View(new MenuModel() { set values... });
    }
}
```

*EditPage.cshtml.cs*

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
     //DO other operations
     ViewComponent("Menu", new { param1, param2, param3 });
}
```

I would appreciate if anyone can guide me how can I reload the ViewComponent from the OnPost() method.

Comment: We probably need to see your HTML/Javascript. Assuming you're posting a form back, add your markup so we can see what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ajax to call handler,and reset the innerHTML,here is a demo:

EditPage.cshtml:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div id="MenuComponent">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Menu", new { param1 = 1, param2 = 2, param3 = 3 })
</div>


<button onclick="change()">change</button>
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        function change() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '?handler=Change',
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            }).done(function (result) {
                document.getElementById("MenuComponent").innerHTML = result;
            });
        }

    </script>
}
```

EditPage.cshtml.cs:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostChangeAsync()
        {
            //DO other operations
            return ViewComponent("Menu", new { param1=2, param2=3, param3=4 });
        }
```

MenuViewComponent :

```
public class MenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int param1,int param2,int param3)
        {
            return View(new MenuModel() {Param1=param1,Param2=param2,Param3=param3});
        }

    }
```

MenuViewComponent View:

```
@model MenuModel
<h1>parama1:@Model.Param1</h1>
<h1>parama2:@Model.Param2</h1>
<h1>parama3:@Model.Param3</h1>
```

MenuModel:

```
public class MenuModel
    {
        public int Param1 { get; set; }
        public int Param2 { get; set; }
        public int Param3 { get; set; }

    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Great!!... It guided me to the solution... I got some more clear ideas from this link: https://www.andriescu.nl/net-c/ajax-call-to-a-viewcomponent-in-net-core-3-1-razor-pages-for-loading-on-demand-part-of-a-web-page/